# How to view value of function arg in GDB that was returned and not defined as standalone variable

Tags: c++, gdb

I'm still getting the hang of c++ and GDB.

I had the following program and I declared and initialized a variable `startPos` before passing it into a function. While stepping with GDB I could `print startPos` after it was evaluated and see what the value is.

```
#include <iostream>                                                             
#include <string>                                                               

int main(){                                                                     
    // replace the word red with blue                                      
    std::string toReplace{ "red" };                                                                                                                         
    std::string str{ "I saw a red car yesterday." }; 

    long unsigned startPos{ str.find("red") };                                
    str.replace(startPos, toReplace.length(), "blue");                                          

    std::cout << str << '\n';                                                   

    return 0;                                                                   
}
```

I decided to not declare `startPos` before and evaluate its value so the return value would be passed as an argument to the `replace` function, like so:

```
#include <iostream>                                                             
#include <string>                                                               

int main(){                                                                     
    // replace the word with red with blue                                      
    std::string toreplace{ "red" };                                             
    std::string str{ "i saw a red car yesterday." };   

    str.replace(str.find("red"), toReplace.length(), "blue");                   

    std::cout << str << '\n';                                                   

    return 0;                                                                   
}
```

But now I cannot view what `str.find("red")` evaluates to when stepping in gdb. I tried `info locals` and `info args` but those don't show me what I need, or I'm using it wrong.

How can I use gdb to see what return values were or what is being passed into the function?

PS: I am skipping stepping into any standard library functions.

Comment: You should reconsider not stepping into the library function, but step into it and then immediately `f`inish, returning from it, and gdb will show the return value.

Comment: Is that the only way? I would prefer not to do it this way since `step` `finish` `step` is a big inconvenience considering the large reuse of the standard lib

Comment: I don't know what "considering the large reuse of the standard lib" means. Whichever way this gets done, a breakpoint has to be set before the function call.  Up until that point there is nothing different about the debugging session, and this boils down with executing three commands, quickly, instead of one. Doesn't seem like a big deal to me, especially since this only needs to be done once or twice, until whatever the original problem is, is debugged, and everyone moves on to bigger and better things.

Comment: I meant,  I don't necessarily know the issue is in a particular block of code. So Ill set a break point at the last location that I know is functional and `step` line by line. I use (reuse) the standard library functions a lot, and if I don't skip all the `/usr/include/*` headers and source files, I will be stepping into them consistently.

but youre saying that if I skip stepping into the standard library functions, there is no other way to view what the args of a function are evaluated to?

Comment: Correct. The debugger cannot see into the future. The debugger cannot tell you which argument get passed into a function call until it actually happens.

Comment: Alright that clears it up. I figured before gdb enters the standard library function (which I am skipping) it would have to execute the functions that will generate the args. But since they are called as arguments in the the standard library function (which I am skipping), they will not be visible. Thanks for your patience!